# Problem about the scope of a global variable

Tags: python, variables, scope

I'm starting to develop in python and I have a problem with the scope of one of my variables

I declare a variable called "bankroll" of integer type and assign it a value of 500 I then use it in a function and pass it as a parameter but at the end of the execution of my function its value remains unchanged I do not understand (the function is defined in another module but is used in the same file or is declared "bankroll")

I tried to return this variable from my function and reassign it to bankroll but its value does not change

```py
# the function taking in parameter bankroll
def roulette(mise,numeroChoisis, bankroll, continuerPartit):

   else:
        print("c'est perdu !")
        bankroll - mise
        math.ceil(bankroll)
        return bankroll

#the main 
bankroll = rouletteGain.roulette(mise, numeroChoisis, bankroll, continuerPartit)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This code doesn't appear valid (`else` without `if`). Can you post the working code? `bankroll - mise` does nothing--did you mean `bankroll -= mise` and `bankroll = math.ceil(bankroll)`?

Comment: the if is before i didnt show it and you solve my probleme my calculations are bad I don't use operators well thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare a variable as `global` in your function in order for it to work as one. Like this:

```
def increment(val):
    global x
    x = x + 1

x = 4
increment(x)
print(x) # 5
```

Comment: I tried but since the base variable is declared in another module I have an error of type "Using global for'bankroll' but no assignment is donepylint(global-variable-not-assigned)"